# dynamic structure giving an error

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

```
int i=0;
void push(int *ptr)
{
    if(i==0)
    {
        ptr= (int *)calloc(1,sizeof(int));
    }
    else
    {
        ptr=(int *)realloc(ptr,sizeof(int)*(i+1));
    }
    i++;
}
```

when i add two or more number  , realloc giving an error(main.exe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have a pointer somewhere else, which you send as an argument to the function "push"?

You need to send a pointer to that pointer, so the "push" function can change its value.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you probably need is to declare the `push` parameter as `int **ptr`, assign to `*ptr`, and call it with `&ptr`.

You also *don't* need the casts and some other stuff, I might suggest:

```
int i=0;

void push(int **ptr)
{
    *ptr = i++ == 0 ? calloc(1,sizeof(int)) : realloc(ptr,sizeof(int)*(i+1));
}
```